# When do you need Modifier.composed { ... }?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

When is `Modifier.composed { ... }` useful? Why would I need it if I could simply do `Modifier.padding()` over `Modifier.composed { PaddingModifier(...) }`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Note - `composed` is no longer the recommended approach for creating Composition-aware `Modifier`. It's now recommended to create Composition-aware `Modifier` like any other Composable:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Modifier.composableModifier(): Modifier {
    val color = LocalContentColor.current.copy(alpha = 0.5f)
    return this then Modifier.background(color)
}

@Composable
fun MyComposable() {
    val composedModifier = Modifier.composableModifier()
}
```

Check out the latest documentation on creating custom `Modifier` for more info:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/custom-modifiers

---

[Modifier.composed](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).composed(kotlin.Function1,%20kotlin.Function1)) allows the creation of a composition-aware modifier-factory that's useful for [materializing](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:compose/ui/ui/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/ComposedModifier.kt;l=59) instance-specific, **stateful** modifiers. From the docs:

> Declare a just-in-time composition of a Modifier that will be composed for each element it modifies. composed may be used to implement stateful modifiers that have instance-specific state for each modified element, allowing the same Modifier instance to be safely reused for multiple elements while maintaining element-specific state.

In other words, it allows you to inject hoisted state into an element-specific `Modifier` and use `remember`, `DisposableEffect`, `Ambient`, etc. For instance:

```kotlin
fun Modifier.fancyModifier(
    enabled: Boolean = false,
    onClick: () -> Unit = {}
) = composed(inspectorInfo = debugInspectorInfo {
    name = "fancyModifier"
    value = enabled
}) {
    var paddingValue by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
    onCommit(enabled) {
        paddingValue = if (enabled) 16.dp else 0.dp
    }
    fillMaxWidth()
        .clickable { onClick() }
        .padding(paddingValue)
}
```

```kotlin
LazyColumnFor(items = List(size = 10) { "$it" }) {
    var enabled by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Text(
        text = "fancy modifier",
        modifier = Modifier.fancyModifier(enabled) {
            enabled = !enabled
        }
    )
}
```

You can also declare `InspectorInfo` to help with debugging by using `debugInspectorInfo`. From the docs:

> If inspectorInfo is specified this modifier will be visible to tools during development. Specify the name and arguments of the original modifier.
> as well as optionally declare `InspectorInfo` to help with debugging.

You can use the `properties` field instead of `value` if you have more than value you'd like to track.

Note: [debugInspectorInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/package-summary.html?hl=in&skip_cache=true#debuginspectorinfo) lambdas are removed from `release` builds.

```kotlin
class FancyModifierTest {

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        isDebugInspectorInfoEnabled = true
    }

    @After
    fun teardown() {
        isDebugInspectorInfoEnabled = false
    }

    @Test
    fun testFancyModifierInspectableValue() {
        val modifier = Modifier.fancyModifier() as InspectableValue
        assertEquals(modifier.nameFallback, "fancyModifier")
        assertEquals(modifier.valueOverride, false)
        assertEquals(modifier.inspectableElements.toList().size, 0)
    }

}
```

Here are some more practical examples:

- [JetSnack Gradient](https://cs.android.com/androidx/compose-samples/+/main:Jetsnack/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetsnack/ui/components/Gradient.kt?q=androidx.compose.ui.composed)
- [JetCaster Gradient](https://cs.android.com/androidx/compose-samples/+/main:Jetcaster/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetcaster/util/GradientScrim.kt?q=androidx.compose.ui.composed)
- [InspectorInfo Samples](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:compose/ui/ui/samples/src/main/java/androidx/compose/ui/samples/InspectorInfoInComposedModifierSamples.kt)
- [cs.android.com](https://cs.android.com/search?q=androidx.compose.ui.composed&start=1)

Comment: I see thank you very much. so in simple terms, `Modifier.composed {  ...  }` bridges "non-compose world" to "compose world", right?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. If you find yourself needing a composition-ware `Modifier`, `composed` is what you're looking for instead of marking it `@Composable`.

Comment: Why is it prompted ‘Unnecessary use of Modifier.composed’ ?

Comment: @gaohomway it prompts that warning when any remember or any side effect is used which makes composed useless if there is no state in the first place.

Comment: @Thracian Or any `CompositionLocal`

Comment: @Farid true, that too.

Answer (score 8):

You can use it store memory heavy objects to not instantiate every time that modifier is called for a specific element.

This one with composed remembers color with index thus after each recomposition it returns color that was randomly created initially.

```
// Creates stateful modifier with multiple arguments
fun Modifier.composedBackground(width: Dp, height: Dp, index: Int) = composed(
    // pass inspector information for debug
    inspectorInfo = debugInspectorInfo {
        // name should match the name of the modifier
        name = "myModifier"
        // add name and value of each argument
        properties["width"] = width
        properties["height"] = height
        properties["index"] = index
    },
    // pass your modifier implementation that resolved per modified element

    factory = {

        val density = LocalDensity.current

        val color: Color = remember(index) {
            Color(
                red = Random.nextInt(256),
                green = Random.nextInt(256),
                blue = Random.nextInt(256),
                alpha = 255
            )
        }

        // add your modifier implementation here
        Modifier.drawBehind {

            val widthInPx = with(density) { width.toPx() }
            val heightInPx = with(density) { height.toPx() }

            drawRect(color = color, topLeft = Offset.Zero, size = Size(widthInPx, heightInPx))
        }
    }
)
```

This one creates a color each time composable is recomposed

```
fun Modifier.nonComposedBackground(width: Dp, height: Dp) = this.then(

    // add your modifier implementation here
    Modifier.drawBehind {

        //  Without remember this color is created every time item using this modifier composed
        val color: Color = Color(
            red = Random.nextInt(256),
            green = Random.nextInt(256),
            blue = Random.nextInt(256),
            alpha = 255
        )

        val widthInPx = width.toPx()
        val heightInPx = height.toPx()

        drawRect(color = color, topLeft = Offset.Zero, size = Size(widthInPx, heightInPx))
    }
)
```

Usage

```
        var counter by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

        Button(
            onClick = { counter++ },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Text(text = "Increase $counter")
        }

        TutorialText2(text = "Modifier.composed")
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
        ) {

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .composedBackground(150.dp, 20.dp, 0)
                    .width(150.dp)
            ) {
                Text(text = "Recomposed $counter")
            }

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .composedBackground(150.dp, 20.dp, 1)
                    .width(150.dp)
            ) {
                Text(text = "Recomposed $counter")
            }
        }

        TutorialText2(text = "Modifier that is not composed")
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
        ) {

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .nonComposedBackground(150.dp, 20.dp)
                    .width(150.dp)
            ) {
                Text(text = "Recomposed $counter")
            }

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .nonComposedBackground(150.dp, 20.dp)
                    .width(150.dp)
            ) {
                Text(text = "Recomposed $counter")
            }
        }
```

Result

[image]

Also in a practical you can create an animated shake modifier for instance

```
fun Modifier.shake(enabled: Boolean) = composed(

    factory = {
        
        val scale by animateFloatAsState(
            targetValue = if (enabled) .9f else 1f,
            animationSpec = repeatable(
                iterations = 5,
                animation = tween(durationMillis = 50, easing = LinearEasing),
                repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse
            )
        )

        Modifier.graphicsLayer {
            scaleX = if (enabled) scale else 1f
            scaleY = if (enabled) scale else 1f
        }
    },
    inspectorInfo = debugInspectorInfo {
        name = "shake"
        properties["enabled"] = enabled
    }
)
```

Usage

```
Icon(
    imageVector = Icons.Default.NotificationsActive,
    contentDescription = null,
    tint = Color.White,
    modifier = Modifier
        .shake(enabled)
        .background(Color.Red, CircleShape)
        .size(50.dp)
        .padding(10.dp)
)
```