# Can I wrap Modifier with remember in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In order to share settings among of compose functions, I create a `class AboutState()` and a compose `fun rememberAboutState()` to persist settings.

I don't know if I can wrap `Modifier` with `remember` in the solution.

The Code A can work well, but I don't know if it maybe cause problem when I wrap `Modifier` with `remember`, I think `Modifier` is special class and it's polymorphic based invoked.

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun ScreenAbout(
    aboutState: AboutState =  rememberAboutState()
) {
   Column() {
       Hello(aboutState)
       World(aboutState)
   }
}

@Composable
fun Hello(
    aboutState: AboutState
) {
    Text("Hello",aboutState.modifier)
}

@Composable
fun World(
    aboutState: AboutState
) {
    Text("World",aboutState.modifier)
}

class AboutState(
    val textStyle: TextStyle,
    val modifier: Modifier=Modifier
) {
    val rowSpace: Dp = 20.dp
}

@Composable
fun rememberAboutState(): AboutState {
    val aboutState = AboutState(
        textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.body1.copy(
            color=Color.Red
        ),
        modifier=Modifier.padding(start = 80.dp)
    )
    return remember {
        aboutState
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There wouldn't be a problem passing a Modifier to a class. What you actually defined above, even if named State, is not class that acts as a State, it would me more appropriate name it as `HelloStyle`, `HelloDefaults.style()`, etc.

It would be more appropriate to name a class `XState` when it should have internal or public `MutableState` that can trigger recomposition or you can get current `State` of `Composable` or `Modifier` due to changes. It shouldn't contain only styling but state mechanism either to change or observe state of the Composble such as `ScrollState` or `PagerState`.

When you have a State wrapper object common way of having a stateful Modifier or Modifier with memory or Modifiers with Compose scope is using `Modifier.composed{}` and passing State to Modifier, not the other way around.

[When do you need Modifier.composed { ... }?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64989659/when-do-you-need-modifier-composed)

```
fun Modifier.composedModifier(aboutState: AboutState) = composed(
    factory = {
        val color = remember { getRandomColor() }
        aboutState.color = color
        Modifier.background(aboutState.color)
    }
)
```

In this example even if it's not practical getRandomColor is created once in recomposition and same color is used.

A zoom modifier i use for zooming in this [library](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Zoom/blob/master/zoom/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/zoom/ZoomModifier.kt) is as

```
fun Modifier.zoom(
    key: Any? = Unit,
    consume: Boolean = true,
    clip: Boolean = true,
    zoomState: ZoomState,
    onGestureStart: ((ZoomData) -> Unit)? = null,
    onGesture: ((ZoomData) -> Unit)? = null,
    onGestureEnd: ((ZoomData) -> Unit)? = null
) = composed(
    factory = {
        val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

        // Current Zoom level
        var zoomLevel by remember { mutableStateOf(ZoomLevel.Min) }

           // Rest of the code

    },
    inspectorInfo = {
        name = "zoom"
        properties["key"] = key
        properties["clip"] = clip
        properties["consume"] = consume
        properties["zoomState"] = zoomState
        properties["onGestureStart"] = onGestureStart
        properties["onGesture"] = onGesture
        properties["onGestureEnd"] = onGestureEnd
    }
)
```

Another practical example for this is Modifier.scroll that uses rememberCoroutineScope(), you can also remember object too to not intantiate another object in recomposition

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
private fun Modifier.scroll(
    state: ScrollState,
    reverseScrolling: Boolean,
    flingBehavior: FlingBehavior?,
    isScrollable: Boolean,
    isVertical: Boolean
) = composed(
    factory = {
        val overscrollEffect = ScrollableDefaults.overscrollEffect()
        val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        // Rest of the code
    },
    inspectorInfo = debugInspectorInfo {
        name = "scroll"
        properties["state"] = state
        properties["reverseScrolling"] = reverseScrolling
        properties["flingBehavior"] = flingBehavior
        properties["isScrollable"] = isScrollable
        properties["isVertical"] = isVertical
    }
)
```